# Trouble Ticket in Microsoft CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4, ticket-system

I'm working on customizing a Microsoft Dynamics CRM (4.0) system for my university as a thesis.
My teacher would like to know if it is possible to implement a ticketing system in the CRM so that the users (not the clients) could generate a trouble ticket. For example if their computer doesn't work properly.
I had a look around the internet and found some software that would handle the ticketing but I couldn't understand if this can be integrated in the CRM

Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CRM contains all the functionality you would need to build a ticket business object and have the user create a new ticket, assign the ticket to a developer or support tech for work, and resolve the ticket (with notes) when the work has been completed. External software would not be required.